# Is it possible to use Kafka in Face Detection process using python and openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, apache-kafka

I'm newer to Kafka framework , what I know exactly for now is that Kafka is about a technology that simplifies the process of messaging between producer and consumer , let's suppose that I have a face detection system that use OpenCV and python :

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam. 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# To use a video file as input 
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.mp4')

while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    # Display
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

Source Code : https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-in-2-minutes-using-opencv-python-90f89d7c0f81

My question in this situation , Is it possible to use Kafka to produce streaming input and detect face in real time ( from producer ) and send it to the consumer ?

[image]

**Update :**

There is a package called Kafka-python , may can help in this case .

Python Package : https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/

Comment: `kafka-python` is simply the Python Kafka client. It will not just help - you need it in order to write producers and consumers in Python (unless you'd rather implement the binary protocol yourself.)

Comment: So it's the same as kafka that is used in Java for example?

Comment: This will help you with [Kafka and Python](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/python). For Kafka and face detection here are a couple of useful examples/references: [Demo of Kafka and OpenCV](https://github.com/starkandwayne/opencv-kafka-demo) [Video Stream Analytics Using OpenCV, Kafka and Spark Technologies](https://www.infoq.com/articles/video-stream-analytics-opencv/)

Comment: Thank you @RobinMoffatt but this are more details , however, I need a good start , did you have other tutorials ?

Comment: Kafka is a stand-alone message broker software written in Scala and Java. Producers and consumers talk to it over the network using a binary protocol. Kafka doesn't care what language those producers and consumers are written in as long as they speak the binary protocol. `kafka-python` is a Python library that speaks the protocol and allows you to write producers and consumers in Python. You can freely mix producers and consumers written in different languages as long as they understand each other's messages.

Comment: I wonder that why do you need kafka for this use case? Kafka is useful when you have high load streaming of data. For face detection purposes I really dont understand what is the case kafka will support you? It is already possible to create very healty real time face detection processes without kafka.

Comment: @EnesUğuroğlu I'm thinking that Kafka will simply the main works by output a stream with a large number of fps , so if I will have a whole number of frame per seconds as an example 60 , it will produce a good prediction and face detection ( deep learning algorithms like CNN not machine learning algorithms ).

Comment: Do you really need 60 fps? Movies/TV shows for example, are only 24 fps.

Comment: Why not ? I think that is possible